# How to push a project to github after renamed a folder locally

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am learning Git. I renamed a folder locally and now could not push a project to GitHub. It shown this message when I push it.

```
push -u origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you rename the folder? Did you use `git mv` or just the plain `mv` command

Comment: This sounds like your configuration got messed up rather than the renaming of a folder being the culprit.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Either way I would not expect this error.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did not use a terminal. I manual renamed it.

Comment: You should have used `git mv`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I already did it. What should I do now?

Comment: was this repo cloned? or is it an existing repo that you want to setup a remote for? i.e. git remote add origin https://path/to/your/git/repo.git. You can run 'git remote -v' to see your remotes.

Answer (score 0):

its `git push -u origin master`.
Therotically, git has nothing to do with the folder names. It traks the whole content.

Comment: I had to ran `git pull` and I could ran `git push`.